# Windows 10 Pro Why are some icons on task bar super tiny

Tags: windows, windows-10

Given:
Windows 10 Pro

Why are some of my icons on task bar super tiny? I have 3 monitors and it only does it on my 43in hdtv screen?

[image]

Comment: The “small icon” isn’t using the correct icon. Without knowing what process it is further explanation is impossible